# Getting error message: “Missing argument for parameter ‘structAttributeName’ in call” Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct, parameters, arguments

I’m getting the following error message: “`Missing argument for parameter ‘hours’  in call`, where “`hours`” is an attribute of a struct, and I’m getting this error message in the line of code: “`var selectedVenue = SelectedRestaurantDetailViewInfoNotUsingCodable()`” in the code snippet further below.

There is a “Fix” button for this error message that says to add in the argument, and have the parameter be assigned to a different struct’s name which is the data type of “`hours`” in the first struct mentioned. The text just to the left of this “Fix” button: “`Insert ', hours: <#OpenHoursForDaysOfWeek#>’`”.

I’ve tried this “Fix” button, except I took out the extra comma and space before "`hours`" in the suggested line of code from the "Fix" button, also the result was the same as when the space and comma I took out were there, as I tried both. In this line of code where the "Fix" button is used, the assignment for the parameter of “`hours`” is set to the data type that the struct attribute also called “`hours`” is set to in the file with these structs, however I get the error message: “`Cannot convert value of type 'OpenHoursForDaysOfWeek.Type' to expected argument type ‘OpenHoursForDaysOfWeek’`" when I do this, where “`OpenHoursForDaysOfWeek`” is the data type that the “`hours`” attribute is set to, and which is a struct itself.

I’ve included the file that I’m receiving this “`Missing argument for parameter ‘hours’ in call`” in the below code snippet, and the file that has both of these struct definitions, where one struct has the “`hours`” attribute, and the other struct is the struct that is the data type for the just mentioned “`hours`” attribute.

**Code:**

`File1-FileImWorkingInThatHasErrorMessage`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

extension UIViewController {

    func retrieveSelectedRestaurantDetailViewInfo(
        selected_restaurant_business_ID: String) async throws -> SelectedRestaurantDetailViewInfoNotUsingCodable? {

            // MARK: Make API Call
            let apiKey = "API key"

            /// Create URL
            let baseURL =
            "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/\(selected_restaurant_business_ID)"

            let url = URL(string: baseURL)

            /// Creating Request
            var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
            request.setValue("Bearer \(apiKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            request.httpMethod = "GET"

            ///Initialize session and task
            //Code for not using completionHandler:
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
                
            do {
                /// Read data as JSON
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])

                /// Main dictionary
                guard let responseDictionary = json as? NSDictionary else {return}

                //Code for accessing restaraunt detail view info, and assigning it to selectedRestarauntDetailViewInfo view model thats a struct.
                //The line of code below is where I'm getting the error message: “Missing argument for parameter ‘hours’  in call".
                var selectedVenue = SelectedRestaurantDetailViewInfoNotUsingCodable()
                
                
                //Rest of code for accessing restaraunt detail view info, and assigning it to seelctedRestarauntDetailViewInfo view model thats a struct.
                selectedVenue.name = responseDictionary?.value(forKey: "name") as? String
                
                //*Rest of code for getting business info including address, hours, etc..*
                //Only the code the code for accessing the hours info is listed here since it may be related to my error message above of “Missing argument for parameter ‘hours’  in call". The rest of the code for accessing other info is similar/in the same format as the line of code above which is "selectedVenue.name = responseDictionary.value(forKey: "name") as? String".
                if let hoursDictionariesForHoursManipulation = responseDictionary?.value(forKey: "hours") as? [NSDictionary] {
                    selectedVenue.hours = self.manipulateSelectedRestaurantHoursInfoAndRecieveFormattedHoursInfoToUse(selected_restaurant_business_hours: hoursDictionariesForHoursManipulation)
                }

                else {
                    selectedVenue.hours = "Hours of Operation for this business are unavailable at this time."
                }
                
                return selectedVenue
                
            } catch {
                print("Caught error")
            }
    }
}
```

`File2-StructsThatAreUsedInFile1`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

struct SelectedRestaurantDetailViewInfoNotUsingCodable {
    var name: String?
    //Rest of attribute definitions for getting data, such as address, image URLs, etc., and are in the same format as the "name" attribute definition in the line of code above.
    var hours: OpenHoursForDaysOfWeek
}

struct OpenHoursForDaysOfWeek {
    var mondayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var tuesdayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var wednesdayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var thursdayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var fridayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var saturdayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var sundayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var numberOfOpenHoursTimeRangesAsStringTypeOfTableViewCellToUse: String
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think that is because in your Struct, the - var hours: OpenHoursForDaysOfWeek must be Optional, such as the - var name: String?. If the attribute is not optional you'll have to declare it somehow when you instantiate it

Comment: You should look into using Codable when decoding your json to avoid this messy code with dictionaries. Other than that the error is pretty clear, you need a value for `hours` to pass to the init. Since you extract such value later in the code I would suggest you simply do things in a different order.

Comment: @DefyingL Sorry for the late reply, I was busy with other things. Thank you, this makes sense, I ended up declaring it when I instantiated it, but may switch to using an optional/the way of using an optional (as other code would also have to be changed) in the future.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Comment 1 of 2: Sorry for the late reply, I was busy with other things. I was considering using Codable for this struct, however I had already written the code for manipulating the business hours to show them how I wanted using NSDictionary, and would rather not have to rewrite that code again for the Codable part, otherwise, I would have used Codable the first time.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Comment 2 of 2: Also, thank you, this makes sense, I completely overlooked having to declare when instantiating here for this error message. I ended up declaring it when I instantiated it, but may switch to using an optional/the way of using an optional (as other code would also have to be changed) in the future. What things you are you suggesting I do in a different order? Declaring it and instantiating it first followed by something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `var hours: OpenHoursForDaysOfWeek?` Optional.

Or if is not Optional, you have to declare the value when you instantiate it

```
var selectedVenue = SelectedRestaurantDetailViewInfoNotUsingCodable(hours: OpenHoursForDaysOfWeek(mondayOpenHoursWithoutDay: "text", 
tuesdayOpenHoursWithoutDay: "text", 
wednesdayOpenHoursWithoutDay: "text", 
thursdayOpenHoursWithoutDay: "text", 
fridayOpenHoursWithoutDay: <"text", 
saturdayOpenHoursWithoutDay: "text", 
sundayOpenHoursWithoutDay: "text", 
numberOfOpenHoursTimeRangesAsStringTypeOfTableViewCellToUse: "text"))
```

Comment: To the answer poster and @Joakim Danielson: Thank you! This solved my problem! I ended up declaring it when I instantiated it, but may switch to using an optional along with the other code changes needed for using the optional in the future as described in the comments further above in the post.